# Takesaki's duality in representation theory of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, c-star-algebras

In M.Takesaki's 1967 [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970350) titled *A Duality in the Representation Theory of C*-Algebras*, admissible operator fields are defined in order to generalize Gelfand transform to a non-abelian setting.

[image]
[image]

What argument did the author have in mind when he wrote that **the fundamental theorem of Gelfand for commutative $C^*$-algebras yields the affirmative answer to this question**? To me, the fact that every abelian $C^*$-algebra has the property $(\mathscr{D})$ is not obvious at all.